# GCC fails(?) to expand complex macro

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

The following jumble of macros compiles correctly under visual studio and the Keil ARM compiler, but is failing for GCC for ARM 6.3.1:

```
#define DRV_ACFGCAL_REG_INDEX(regulator_name,register_num)  ((ACFG_CFG##register_num##_EN##regulator_name##_LSB+3)/4 + ((register_num-2)*8))
#define DRV_ACFGCAL_RESET_INDEX(reset_name,reg_offset)       ((ACFG_CFG##reg_offset##_R##reset_name##_LSB)+((reg_offset-1)*32))
#define DRV_ACFGCAL_INFO(rst,rst_reg,idx,docx,regi,vtr,pdcal) \
                                                             {                                       \
                                                             0                                      ,\
                                                             0                                      ,\
                                                             idx##_ACFG_IDX                         ,\
                                                             docx##_WORD_COUNT                      ,\
                                                             DRV_ACFGCAL_RESET_INDEX(rst,rst_reg)   ,\
                                                             DRV_ACFGCAL_REG_INDEX(rst,##regi##)   ,\
                                                             docx##_##vtr##_LSB                     ,\
                                                             docx##_##vtr##_OFFSET                  ,\
                                                             docx##_##pdcal##_VTRCAL_MASK           ,\
                                                             docx##_##pdcal##_VTRCAL_RESET_VALUE    ,\
                                                             }
#define DRV_ACFGCAL_INFOn(rst,rst_reg,idx,docx,regi,vtr,pdcal) \
                                                             {                                       \
                                                             0                                      ,\
                                                             0                                      ,\
                                                             idx##_ACFG_IDX                         ,\
                                                              docx##_WORD_COUNT                     ,\
                                                             DRV_ACFGCAL_RESET_INDEX(rst,rst_reg)   ,\
                                                             DRV_ACFGCAL_REG_INDEX(rst,##regi##)   ,\
                                                             0                                      ,\
                                                             0                                      ,\
                                                             0                                      ,\
                                                             0                                      ,\
                                                             }

/* Some blocks with reset bits don't have regulator bits. Deal with it by creating bogus values
 * that can be used to identify those blocks in code. */

#define ACFG_CFGNONE_ENDAC01_LSB    (NONE_INDEX*4)
#define ACFG_CFGNONE_ENDAC23_LSB    (NONE_INDEX*4)
#define ACFG_CFGNONE_ENDAC45_LSB    (NONE_INDEX*4)
#define ACFG_CFGNONE_ENREFCAL_LSB   (NONE_INDEX*4)
#define ACFG_CFGNONE_ENTESTADC_LSB  (NONE_INDEX*4)


#define ACFG_NONE_ENNONE_LSB        7
#define ACFG_NONE_ENNONE_OFFSET     2
#define ACFG_NONE_ENDAC01_LSB       ACFG_NONE_ENNONE_LSB
#define ACFG_NONE_ENDAC01_OFFSET    ACFG_NONE_ENNONE_OFFSET
#define ACFG_NONE_ENDAC23_LSB       ACFG_NONE_ENNONE_LSB
#define ACFG_NONE_ENDAC23_OFFSET    ACFG_NONE_ENNONE_OFFSET
#define ACFG_NONE_ENDAC45_LSB       ACFG_NONE_ENNONE_LSB
#define ACFG_NONE_ENDAC45_OFFSET    ACFG_NONE_ENNONE_OFFSET
#define ACFG_NONE_ENREFCAL_LSB      ACFG_NONE_ENNONE_LSB
#define ACFG_NONE_ENREFCAL_OFFSET   ACFG_NONE_ENNONE_OFFSET
#define ACFG_NONE_ENTESTADC_LSB     ACFG_NONE_ENNONE_LSB
#define ACFG_NONE_ENTESTADC_OFFSET  ACFG_NONE_ENNONE_OFFSET
#define NONE (2)
#define NONE_INDEX  (63)

#define ACFG_INFO_addr(block)  ((g_drv_acfg_info[block].m_index << 4) | FIRST_ACFG_BASE_ADDR)
#define DAC01_ACFG_IDX 1
#define DAC_WORD_COUNT 5
#define ACFG_CFG1_RDAC01_LSB 0
#define DAC_TESTA_T_VTR_LSB 1
#define DAC_TESTA_T_VTR_OFFSET 1
#define DAC_PDCAL_VTRCAL_MASK 0xf
#define DAC_PDCAL_VTRCAL_RESET_VALUE 0


typedef struct {
    unsigned m_bEnabled     : 1;
    unsigned m_caled        : 1; /**< 0 until calibration occurs. After being set, cal will not occur again */
    unsigned m_index        : 9; /**< The base index of the hardware block */
    unsigned m_count        : 5; /**< Number of registers in this hardware block */
    unsigned m_resetIdx     : 6; /**< which bit index (0-63) the reset for this block sits*/
    unsigned m_regulatorIdx : 6; /**< which group of 3 controls the regulator for this block, 63 for none*/
    unsigned m_vtrlsb       : 4; /**< Left bit shifts into the testa register of a block to
                                      place VTR on diaga */
    unsigned m_vtroffset    : 4; /**< Offset from base address of a block to the register containing
                                      the bit for VTR on diaga */
    unsigned m_vtrmask      : 8; /**< The mask of the calcode register for a given block */
    unsigned m_vtrcache     : 7; /**< The starting calcode for a given block */
} drv_acfg_info_t;

drv_acfg_info_t g_drv_acfg_info[] = {
/*                     rst   rst       idx      docx     acfg       VTR on       CAL 
 *                     name  reg#      name     name     reg#     diagA name    regname function
 *                     ------ ------ --------  --------  ----- ----------------- ------ ----- */
    DRV_ACFGCAL_INFO (DAC01,1,DAC01,DAC,NONE,TESTA_T_VTR,PDCAL),    //ACFG_BLK_DAC01,
};
```

There appears to be some issue with the preprocessor not fully expanding things, as hinted at by the errors:

```
output/gcc_cortex_m3/simple/objs/main.c.o :
   + tests/simple/main.c
"C:/usr/gcc_arm/6_2017-q2-update"/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe   -J"C:/usr/gcc_arm/6_2017-q2-update"/arm-none-eabi/include -MD -MF output/gcc_cortex_m3/simple/objs/main.c.d  -E -J"C:/usr/gcc_arm/6_2017-q2-update"/arm-none-eabi/include -I. -D__MICROLIB  -include gcc_preinclude.h -E -Dsi4790     -O3 -Os -g -D_DEBUG --no-exceptions  -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3    -c -o output/gcc_cortex_m3/simple/objs/main.c.o tests/simple/main.c
tests/simple/main.c:17:87: error: pasting "," and "NONE" does not give a valid preprocessing token
                                                              DRV_ACFGCAL_REG_INDEX(rst,##regi##)   ,\
                                                                                       ^
tests/simple/main.c:91:5: note: in expansion of macro 'DRV_ACFGCAL_INFO'
     DRV_ACFGCAL_INFO (DAC01,1,DAC01,DAC,NONE,TESTA_T_VTR,PDCAL),    //ACFG_BLK_DAC01,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tests/simple/main.c:91:41: error: pasting "NONE" and ")" does not give a valid preprocessing token
     DRV_ACFGCAL_INFO (DAC01,1,DAC01,DAC,NONE,TESTA_T_VTR,PDCAL),    //ACFG_BLK_DAC01,
                                         ^
tests/simple/main.c:17:90: note: in definition of macro 'DRV_ACFGCAL_INFO'
                                                              DRV_ACFGCAL_REG_INDEX(rst,##regi##)   ,\
                                                                                          ^~~~
make: *** [output/gcc_cortex_m3/simple/objs/main.c.o] Error 1
```

I do apologize for this amazing amount of stuff crammed together, but we're working in a deeply embedded environment where we need to take auto-generated header files for registers without a very regular layout (or naming conventions) and try to make something out of them.  We end up with this sort of crazyness all over trying to make the hardware look sane.

I need to find a way to 'make it work' under GCC.   Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong?  Do I need to massage my macros (and how?) or do I need to prod GCC into looking at them differently?

Comment: What is `,##regi` supposed to do? Don't you mean `,regi`?

Comment: @melpomene It's supposed to create the text `DRV_ACFGCAL_RESET_INDEX(2,NONE)` because the `NONE` is used to create another symbol from that macro `ACFG_CFGNONE_ENDAC01_LSB`.    Without the `##regi##` then `NONE` expands to `2` which is not what is desired.

Comment: That makes no sense to me because that's not what `##` does.

Comment: `##` is used to paste strings together in macros, no?  We use it to paste `DRV_ACFGCAL_REG_INDEX(rst,` and `NONE` and `)` together to form `DRV_ACFGCAL_REG_INDEX(rst,NONE)`

Comment: No, `##` is used to paste tokens together. As gcc says, `,NONE` is not a valid token. The preprocessor doesn't work on strings; it's all stream-of-tokens.

Comment: @melpomene Do you have a suggestion as to how to approach the problem?

Comment: Does `NONE` have to be defined? Removing `#define NONE (2)` (or moving it below) would fix the issue. Anyway, I must say this is a school example of preprocessor abuse. What are you trying to achieve, actually?

Comment: Undefining `NONE` doesn't solve the problem.   Like I said, our hardware designers don't create registers to control the hardware with software in mind, so their bits aren't regularly spaced or regularly named and we have to create abstractions to deal with this that don't take up much memory.  macro abuse like this allows for self checking code and creating tables of something much more readable--once you get past the obscene macros.

Comment: @RussSchultz Groo I'm certain was implying that removing `#define NONE (2)` _as opposed to_ relying on UB (pastes that don't result in tokens; note 6.10.3.3p3: "If the result is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is undefined.") would fix the issue.  That implies that the proposal should not only remove `NONE`, it should change `,##regi##)` to `,regi)`. ...

Comment: The _bigger_ issue is that people here can fix your problem easily, but we don't know what the "this" is in "macro abuse like this allows ..."; i.e., we don't know what your constraints are.  Can you change the macro names in your code?  (will using "pp-numbers" like `0NONE`, which can never conflict, "work" for you?)  Can you live without `NONE`?  (Why do you even need `NONE`?  There may very well be a reason, but in this code it's not used).  We're not looking for a rationale, we're looking for the invariants under which we can propose solutions.

Comment: @HWalters long run, I can change a lot.  short run, I don't need to solve the problem "correctly". I'm doing code density analysis with various architectures and compilers, so spending a lot of time to make it compile AND work isn't useful (I can't validate correctness since I don't have hardware or simulators for the platforms in question) so I'm just going to get rid of the intializers and move on.   There are probably 10+ different ugly macro systems in the code base so solving this one won't resolve the others unless it's a simple "do this instead", which I don't think exists.

Comment: Hwalters, groo & melpomene  I do appreciate all of your help and insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is some compilers are more lenient in what the pre-processor can use with the `##` operator.

Visual Studio and the Keil ARM compiler allow basically anything to be pasted together; GCC will only paste 'preprocessor tokens' (which don't include `,` or `.` or `)`;do a websearch on `preprocessor tokens` to find a much better reference than I can provide).

The takeaway lesson is:  if you do crazy macro abuse, expect GCC to be pickier and potentially break what you want to do.